# Implement phone call lengh monitoring iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I can make user to call from my app.  I want to get the length of the call in my app, Once the call is ended

Comment: OK, what's your question?

Answer (score 0):

No,You can't get that officially.As once you initiate `telprompt://` it would leave your application & once the call has been ended there is **no** delegate to be called later and you are outside your app.You can't access any call related information in **non-jailbroken** phone.

Answer (score 0):

Well below link will surely help.

https://iosstuff.wordpress.com/2011/08/19/accessing-iphone-call-history/

But for sure, for sure Apple will reject the app.